# Using array of arguments to call a function via pointer

Tags: c++, api, oop, variadic-functions

I am writing my own reflection library and this is the scenario I am facing:

Base class Method providing the interface for querying stuff about methods and calling them (hence the variadic template method)

```
class Method : public INamedEntity
{
public:
   ...
   template<typename... TArgs>
   void Call(void* instance, TArgs&&... args) const
   {
     AnyType arguments[] = { args... };
     size_t nArguments = sizeof...(TArgs);
     _Call(instance, arguments, nArguments);
   }

   void Call(void* instance) const;

protected:
  // This was supposed to be the link to the derived class
  virtual void _Call(void* instance, AnyType arguments[], size_t count) const = 0;
};
```

The meat and all the implementation is in derived class which is templated (TMethod) and uses the types passed in to deduce stuff like argument types, correct member pointer signature etc.

```
template<typename TReturn, typename TClass, class... Args>
class TMethod<TReturn(TClass, Args...)> : public Method
{
  typedef TReturn(TClass::*MethodPointer)(Args...);

public:
  TMethod(MethodPointer method)
    , m_pointer(method)
  {}
  ...
protected:
  void _Call(void* instance, AnyType arguments[], size_t count) const
  {
    /// ???
    (((TClass*)instance)->*m_pointer)( _How to even call this_ );
  }

private:    
  MethodPointer m_pointer;
  const Type* m_clazz;
  const Type* m_return;
  HashedString m_name;
};
```

Obviously the above code is not what I aim after and honestly I have no clue how to find a workaround for this problem. Of course I am not insisting on expanding the parameter pack into array and passing it like this, as I would really like any working method at the moment. How would you approach passing the arguments from the base class Call function and route it in some usable fashion to the derived implementation?

I am open to any suggestions but I am aware of the possibility of creating a big if statements and making overloads with 'n' number of parameters in the derived class but this seems to be the least elegant solution I come up with till now.

Also I anyone has a better title for this question please let me know ;)

Comment: Side note: As for the `n` overloads ... [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) could help with generating them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but boost is out of the picture ;)

Comment: No time for full answer now, but a few pointers: *n* overloads could be free functions overloaded on the type (actually argument cound) of the pointer-to-function type. Basically `call(T *t, R (T::*m)(), AnyType a[], size_t) { return (t->*m)(); }`; `call(T *t, R (T::*m)(A1), AnyType a[], size_t) { return (t->*m)(a[0]); }` etc.

Comment: One more thing: your identifier `_Call` is illegal. Names starting with underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the compiler & standard library.